# mysql-connector-net-6.3.6 (for .net framework) not showing up in ODBC datasource

Tags: .net, mysql, visual-studio-2008, connector

I've installed mysql-connector-net-6.3.6 to integrate mysql support into my C# project in Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition with visual C#.net.

But after I install the tool nothing is showing up into ODBC datasource application under Administrative tool in my Window Xp machine.

Also nothing appears new in visual studio as well.

Any suggestion or guidelines to handle this?

Thanks in advance....

Regards,
Mustafa Kamal

Answer (score 0):

You won't find it in ODBC datasource after installation, because it is not an ODBC driver(it is ADO.NET driver). You will find some MySQL DLLs in GAC and traces in machine.config instead.

Also, there is no integration of .NET connector into VS Express, because VS Express does not support extensibility.

Answer (score -1):

After installing the MySQL ODBC driver on Windows XP, the driver does not appears in the Drivers tab of the ODBC Data Source Administrator.

Try using Regedit to view the registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers

Select and delete the (DEFAULT) string, then restart the computer.

WARNING - WARNING - WARNING: Editing your Registry incorrectly can cause serious, system wide problems that may require you to reinstall your operating system to correct. It is advised that you back up your registry before modifying it.